# MySQLi fetch error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to move from `MySQL_query` to `MySQLi_query` at the moment I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in

I searched Google but nothing helped me. Maybe here someone will be able to!

This is my code:

**Connection:**

```
$objConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost","konstyle","root", "konstyle") or die(mysqli_error());
```

**SQL Query:**

```
$objQuery_category = mysqli_query($objConnect, $sql_category) or die ("Error Query [".$sql_category."]");
```

**Fetch Array:**

```
while($objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objConnect, $objQuery_category))
```

Why am I getting the error/warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to lose the `$objConnect` when fetching. This should work:

```
while($objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery_category))
```

This is straight from the [manual](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array):

> mixed mysqli_fetch_array ( mysqli_result $result [, int $resulttype = MYSQLI_BOTH ] )

Two arguments: 1st your `mysqli_result` and then the optional result type.

The reason for this is that the connection is already "saved" within `$objQuery_category` after this line: `$objQuery_category = mysqli_query($objConnect, $sql_category)`

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
while($objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objConnect, $objQuery_category))
```

the $objQuery_category should come first, then the result_type.  Try this...

```
while( $objResult =  mysqli_fetch_array( $objQuery_category, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {}
```

Also, take a look at "https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array" also, as this should help explain it better.